# JDBC `decimal(28,2)` becomes `java.sql.Types.DOUBLE`

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sqldatatypes, jtds

There is a `decimal(28, 2)` column in the database. JDBC [getColumnType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) returns `java.sql.Types.DOUBLE` for that column. 
Any ideas why this happens and how to avoid this?

For `decimal(38, 19)` it returns `java.sql.Types.DECIMAL` as expected.

The driver is jtds. Works under Java 1.6. DBMS is MS SQL.

Comment: Is that case where mapping to `java.sql.Types.DOUBLE` happens a straight `SELECT` from the table or some more complex query with some `joins` or so? I mean the stmt from which you gained the `ResultSetMetaData` object. +1 btw

Comment: This post contains 2 links to MSFT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236569/sql-server-data-type-mapping-to-jdbc-data-types

Comment: @FabianBarney, yes, it takes values of a complex query with multiple joins and unions. The original column type is `decimal(28,2)`.

Comment: @home, the link says that `decimal` is always `java.sql.Types.DECIMAL`. But it isn't at least with jtds :)

Comment: @khachik: yep, IMHO either the article or the SQL Server JDBC driver are buggy :-)

Comment: It seems like a driver issue to me. Are you able to test it with a simple `SELECT`. So we may know if it's always mapping DECIMAL(28,2) to DOUBLE or just because the driver got confused by the complex query?! (While googling I realized that there were such issues with jtds in the past.)

Comment: My thought is that the decimal is unable to contain what's coming back.  If you believe that it is able, try casting it in your code and see what happens.

Comment: @FabianBarney, I dug into the code of jtds. It reads different types from the socket for `decimal(38,19)` and `decimal(28,2)` (106 and 109) so it is a server issue. Has anyone ever met this behavior?

Answer (score -3):

Thats correct behaviour. What would you expect it to be? If you want integer types your column should be an INT

Comment: I expect `java.sql.Types.DECIMAL`.